# What are the possible causes of File.getAbsolutePath() returning null?

Tags: java, file-io

I'm running into a bug that appears to be caused by `File.getAbsolutePath()` returning `null`.  What conditions could cause this?  (The system seeing the exception is running Windows XP.)

The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29) has a brief description of the path resolution procedure, but doesn't mention any situation that would result in a `null` path string being returned.

Comment: You could write up a test class that checks for files/directories that definitely exists, and for ones that definitely don't. Then compare the results.

Comment: You mentioned an exception, but didn't mention which one or post the stack trace it printed.  Care to enlighten us with those?

Comment: The exception is somewhat tangential.  It's a NullPointerException caused by doing String string = file.getAbsolutePath() followed by passing the string to a method that expects it to not be null.

Comment: Somehow related to permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious I suppose -- When the file is not instantiated or doesn't exist

Comment: If the `File` wasn't instantiated, then it would throw a `NullPointerException`, not return null.

Comment: Plus, a non-existant file will still resolve to an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Tracing through the API classes, the answer should be in `Win32FileSystem.resolve(File)` (look in your `src.zip` file)

You could always copy/paste the code from this method into your own project and then step through it with the `File` that's causing the problem.